# Problems connecting the new Unity input system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it. I was trying to migrate to a new input system and decided to heavily rewrite my player controller script (Nick). But for some reason the player just stands still even though the debugger detects the input device. I feel like I've made some stupid mistake, but after a lot of analysis, I really couldn't find a solution to it. I will be very grateful if you help me.

Controller script:

```
namespace Nick
{
    public class NickController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] [Range(1, 5)] private float _speed;

        [SerializeField] private Animator _animator;
        [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody2d;

        private float _horizontalInput;

        private Transform _positionLoadNick;
        private float _verticalInput;
        private InputSystem _input;

        private void Awake()
        {
            _input = new InputSystem();
            //_input.Player.Interact.performed += context => Interact();
        }

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            _input.Enable();
        }

        private void OnDisable()
        {
            _input.Disable();
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            Vector2 moveDirectrion = _input.Player.Move.ReadValue<Vector2>();
            MoveNick(moveDirectrion);

        }

        private void MoveNick(Vector2 moveDirectrion)
        {
            if (GameFlow.isMovementFreezed)
            {
                _animator.SetInteger("UpDown", 0);
                _animator.SetInteger("Side", 0);
                return;
            }

            Vector2 position = _rigidbody2d.position;
            position.x += _speed * _horizontalInput * Time.deltaTime;
            position.y += _speed * _verticalInput * Time.deltaTime;
            _animator.SetInteger("UpDown", _verticalInput < 0 ? -1 : (int)Math.Ceiling(_verticalInput));
            _animator.SetInteger("Side", _horizontalInput < 0 ? -1 : (int)Math.Ceiling(_horizontalInput));
            _rigidbody2d.MovePosition(position);
        }
    }
}
```

I will also attach a screenshot from the configurator:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoWAM.png)

I have already indicated all my actions in the code. Nothing helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new InputSystem has multiple approaches (workflows) to bind and retrive the inputs on the script. Is not quite clear if you're using PlayerInput Component or Embbeded Actions, but none of them tries to get the inputs from InputSystem class, but I suggest you take a look in the docs that certainly will make things more clear

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.5/manual/Workflows.html

Answer (score 1):

In `MoveNick` you are still using the (apparently legacy) `_horizontalInput` and `_verticalInput`.

These two are never assigned in your code and will always stay `0`.

You rather want to use the passed `moveDirectrion` (typo btw).